# Number format exception is thrown in android java

Tags: java

Number format exception is thrown for code:

```
String id=etgetinfo.getText().toString();
long l= Long.parseLong(id);
```

Log cat:

> 08-30 11:13:00.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1554): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-30 11:13:00.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1554): Process:
>   com.tarragon.tmessenger, PID: 1554 08-30 11:13:00.995:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1554): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long:
>   "" 08-30 11:13:00.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):    at
>   java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124) 08-30 11:13:00.995:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1554):   at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:345)
>   08-30 11:13:00.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):   at
>   java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:318) 08-30 11:13:00.995:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1554):   at
>   com.tarragon.tmessenger.SqliteExample.onClick(SqliteExample.java:78)
>   08-30 11:13:00.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):   at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 08-30 11:13:00.995:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1554):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 08-30
>   11:13:00.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

Comment: Seems that you're receiving something that's not a parseable number in your `String`. Make sure that there's not even blank spaces around your number.

Comment: `Invalid long: ""` I wonder what that means. Maybe that an empty String cannot be parsed to a number? ...

Answer (score 1):

Your `String` is `""` and that's not a number - you could do a check for this case like

```
long l=(id != null && id.trim().length() > 0) ? Long.parseLong(id.trim()) : 0;
```

Or, add a try {} catch block and a default value like

```
long l = 0;
try {
  l = Long.parseLong((id != null) ? id.trim() : "0");
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1554): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "" 08-30 11:13:00.995:
```

means the string you're trying to parse is in fact the empty string. That doesn't map to a valid long, so you get an exception. You might want to check for special cases like this or use a `try..catch` to handle them gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code and check are you are converting number

```
    long l=0;
    String res=etgetinfo.getText().toString().trim();
    if(!res.equals(""))
    l=Long.valueOf(res);
```